# What does ' (single quotes) means in pseudocode

Tags: pseudocode

I was reading lecture about [Greedy Strategies for Interval Scheduling](http://web.cs.dal.ca/~nzeh/Teaching/3110/Notes/greedy.pdf)

and i came across this symbol  `S
′
←∅`. I have no idea what it means. does anyone know?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`S′` is just the name of a variable.  It is read as "[S prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_%28symbol%29)".  So the code `S′ ←∅` sets the variable `S′` equal to an empty set.

Comment: so is there any difference between S and S prime?

Comment: Yes, they are completely separate variables in the code, but the reader can infer that "S prime" is related to "S" within the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

That's not "S quote" -- it's "S prime". It is standard mathematical notation to use the "prime" symbol to indicate something that is related to or derived from something else.

So in this case, the variable "S prime" is a variable that is derived from "S".